# Dimensionality of tensor from my WaveNet incompatible with PyTorch cross_entropy function

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network, tensor

I've been doing a project regarding making my own WaveNet implementation as Deepmind delivered early in the 2016's in Python.
[image: WaveNet Architecture]

Preprocessing includes mu law encoding, and one hot encoding. The model itself functions well, my problem lies in the loss function torch.nn.functional.cross_entropy used during training, found here: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.functional.html

Particularly, the relation between my output and my target tensors, namely

```
input_tensor.shape = tensor([1, 256, 225332]) # [batch_size, sample_size, audio_length]
output.shape = tensor([1, 256, 225332])
```

According to F.cross_entropy, I must have output = (N, C) and target = input_tensor = (N).
My supervisor told me to do the following:

```
output = output.T.reshape(-1, 256) = tensor([225332, 256])
target = input_tensor.T.long() = tensor([225332, 256, 1]) # This needs to be 1-dimensional, help?
```

For anyone interested in the explicit code, below:
NOTE - the receptive field is not padded, so just for debugging purposes I have subtracted it, while I do know this is not *natural*.

```
>>> output.T.reshape(-1, 256).shape
torch.Size([225332, 256])
>>> input_tensor[:, :, model.input_size - model.output_size:].T.shape
torch.Size([225332, 256, 1])
>>> loss = F.cross_entropy(output.T.reshape(-1, 256), input_tensor[:, :, model.input_size - model.output_size:].T.long().to(device))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.3.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_exec2.py", line 3, in Exec
    exec(exp, global_vars, local_vars)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\JaQtae\anaconda3\envs\CortiGit\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py", line 2693, in cross_entropy
    return nll_loss(log_softmax(input, 1), target, weight, None, ignore_index, None, reduction)
  File "C:\Users\JaQtae\anaconda3\envs\CortiGit\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py", line 2388, in nll_loss
    ret = torch._C._nn.nll_loss(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index)
RuntimeError: 1D target tensor expected, multi-target not supported
```

Somewhat of a novice-in-training with ML and AI, particularly the PyTorch library.

Would appreciate any advice regarding how I should tackle this issue.

The training:

```
model = Wavenet(layers=3,blocks=2,output_size=32).to(device)
model.apply(initialize) # Initialize causalconv1d() with xavier_uniform_ weights and bias of 0.
model.train()


optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.0003)
for i, batch in tqdm(enumerate(train_loader)):
    mu_enc_my_x = encode_mu_law(x=batch, mu=256)
    input_tensor = one_hot_encoding(mu_enc_my_x)

    input_tensor = input_tensor.to(device)
    output = model(input_tensor)
    # TODO: Inspect input/output formats, maybe something wrong....
    loss = F.cross_entropy(output.T.reshape(-1, 256), input_tensor[:,:,model.input_size - model.output_size:].long().to(device)) # subtract receptive field instead of pad it, workaround for quick debugging of loss-issue.
    print("\nLoss:", loss.item())
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

    if i % 1000 == 0:
        print("\nSaving model")
        torch.save(model.state_dict(), "wavenet.pt")
```

The purpose is to get my loss function to work properly, so that I can generate sound files. The current ones with my bad loss function obviously return pure noise.

My full model if any help.

```
"""
Wavenet model

Sources:
https://github.com/kan-bayashi/PytorchWaveNetVocoder/blob/master/wavenet_vocoder/nets/wavenet.py
https://github.com/r9y9/wavenet_vocoder/blob/master/wavenet_vocoder/wavenet.py
https://github.com/Dankrushen/Wavenet-PyTorch/blob/master/wavenet/models.py
https://github.com/vincentherrmann/pytorch-wavenet
"""

from torch import nn
import torch

#TODO: Add local and global conditioning


def initialize(m):
    """
    Initialize CNN with Xavier_uniform weight and 0 bias.
    """
    if isinstance(m, torch.nn.Conv1d):
        nn.init.xavier_uniform_(m.weight)
        nn.init.constant_(m.bias, 0.0)


class CausalConv1d(torch.nn.Module):
    """
    Causal Convolution for WaveNet
    Causality can be introduced with padding as (kernel_size - 1) * dilation (see Keras documentation)
    or it can be introduced as follows according to Golbin.
    https://github.com/golbin/WaveNet/blob/05545339096c3a1d9909d96fb19da4fbae28d8c6/wavenet/networks.py#L38

    Else, look at the following article, several ways to implement it using PyTorch:
    https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/1333

    - Jakob
    """

    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, dilation = 1, bias = True):
        super(CausalConv1d, self).__init__()
        # padding=1 for same size(length) between input and output for causal convolution
        self.dilation = dilation
        self.kernel_size = kernel_size
        self.in_channels = in_channels
        self.out_channels = out_channels
        self.padding = padding = (kernel_size-1) * dilation # kernelsize = 2, -1 * dilation = 1, = 1. - Jakob.
        self.conv = torch.nn.Conv1d(in_channels, out_channels,
                                    kernel_size, padding=padding, dilation=dilation,
                                    bias=bias)  # Fixed for WaveNet but not sure


    def forward(self, x):
        output = self.conv(x)
        if self.padding != 0:
            output = output[:, :, :-self.padding]
        return output





class Wavenet(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self,
                 layers=3,
                 blocks=2,
                 dilation_channels=32,
                 residual_block_channels=512,
                 skip_connection_channels=512,
                 output_channels=256,
                 output_size=32,
                 kernel_size=3
                 ):

        super(Wavenet, self).__init__()

        self.layers = layers
        self.blocks = blocks
        self.dilation_channels = dilation_channels
        self.residual_block_channels = residual_block_channels
        self.skip_connection_channels = skip_connection_channels
        self.output_channels = output_channels
        self.kernel_size = kernel_size
        self.output_size = output_size

        # initialize dilation variables
        receptive_field = 1
        init_dilation = 1


        # List of layers and connections
        self.dilations = []
        self.residual_convs = nn.ModuleList()
        self.filter_conv_layers = nn.ModuleList()
        self.gate_conv_layers = nn.ModuleList()
        self.skip_convs = nn.ModuleList()


        # First convolutional layer
        self.first_conv = CausalConv1d(in_channels=self.output_channels,
                                    out_channels=residual_block_channels,
                                    kernel_size = 2)

        # Building the Modulelists for the residual blocks
        for b in range(blocks):
            additional_scope = kernel_size - 1
            new_dilation = 1
            for i in range(layers):
                # dilations of this layer
                self.dilations.append((new_dilation, init_dilation))

                # dilated convolutions
                self.filter_conv_layers.append(nn.Conv1d(in_channels=residual_block_channels, out_channels=dilation_channels, kernel_size=kernel_size, dilation=new_dilation))

                self.gate_conv_layers.append(nn.Conv1d(in_channels=residual_block_channels, out_channels=dilation_channels, kernel_size=kernel_size, dilation=new_dilation))

                # 1x1 convolution for residual connection
                self.residual_convs.append(nn.Conv1d(in_channels=dilation_channels, out_channels=residual_block_channels, kernel_size=1))

                # 1x1 convolution for skip connection
                self.skip_convs.append(nn.Conv1d(in_channels=dilation_channels,
                                                 out_channels=skip_connection_channels,
                                                 kernel_size=1))

                # Update receptive field and dilation
                receptive_field += additional_scope
                additional_scope *= 2
                init_dilation = new_dilation
                new_dilation *= 2

        # Last two convolutional layers
        self.last_conv_1 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=skip_connection_channels,
                                  out_channels=skip_connection_channels,
                                  kernel_size=1)

        self.last_conv_2 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=skip_connection_channels,
                                    out_channels=output_channels,
                                    kernel_size=1)


        #Calculate model receptive field and the required input size for the given output size
        self.receptive_field = receptive_field
        self.input_size = receptive_field + output_size - 1

    def forward(self, input):

        # Feed first convolutional layer with input
        x = self.first_conv(input)

        # Initialize skip connection
        skip = 0

        # Residual block
        for i in range(self.blocks * self.layers):

            (dilation, init_dilation) = self.dilations[i]

            # Residual connection bypassing dilated convolution block
            residual = x

            # input to dilated convolution block
            filter = self.filter_conv_layers[i](x)
            filter = torch.tanh(filter)
            gate = self.gate_conv_layers[i](x)
            gate = torch.sigmoid(gate)
            x = filter * gate

            # Feed into 1x1 convolution for skip connection
            s = self.skip_convs[i](x)

            #Adding skip & Match size with decreasing dimensionality of x
            if skip is not 0:
                skip = skip[:, :, -s.size(2):]
            skip = s + skip # Sum all skip connections

            # Feed into 1x1 convolution for residual connection
            x = self.residual_convs[i](x)
            #Adding Residual & Match size with decreasing dimensionality of x
            x = x + residual[:, :, dilation * (self.kernel_size - 1):]


            # print(x.shape)

        x = torch.relu(skip)
        #Last conv layers
        x = torch.relu(self.last_conv_1(x))
        x = self.last_conv_2(x)
        soft = torch.nn.Softmax(dim=1)
        x = soft(x)
        return x
```

**EDIT: added code snippet of train for clarity, and full model**

Comment: It is always good to post the error message together with the full traceback.